# How do I grab key value pairs from a group of tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have a group of key value pairs on a document. They are sets of 2 inputs. I'll also need to reject any non-pairs, so if there is only a key or only a value, I don't want one of those sides included.

Like this, input1 is key, input2 is value:

```
<div id = "group_o_inputs">
    <div class="ind_form">
        <input class="input1" type="text"><input class="input2" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="ind_form">
        <input class="input1" type="text"><input class="input2" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="ind_form">
        <input class="input1" type="text"><input class="input2" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

How could I extract these, I am thinking of putting them into a json array. I am thinking of a syntax like this:

```
          var items1 = $("#group_o_inputs .ind_form .input1");
          var items2 = $("#group_o_inputs .ind_form .input2");
```

Then I can use the two arrays with a for loop or something?  And like I mentioned, since the user can leave one input out by accident, I'd like to account for that. Eventually it would come out like this:

```
{
 key: value, key: value, key: value, key: value
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate the `ind_form` class and map an array of objects

```
var data = $('.ind_form').has('.input1,.input2').map(function(){  
     return {
        key   :  $(this).find('.input1').val(),
        value :  $(this).find('.input2').val()
     }
}).get();
```

Produces

```
[
    {key: 'input1-1 value', value : 'input2-1 value'},
    {key: 'input1-2 value', value : 'input2-2 value'}   
]
```

Comment: I don't really want it to say `{key: 'input1-1 value', value : 'input2-1 value'},
    {key: 'input1-2 value', value : 'input2-2 value'} `. What I want it to say is: `{
 key: value, key: value, key: value, key: value
}`

Comment: Ok... do similar loop then using `each` and add new key and value to single object. Are you already checking for duplicates before this runs?